# Form Recognizer Train Fails InvalidContentSourceFormat: Invalid content source: Could not read build content

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-services

I spent a good amount of time marking up custom extraction models on some PDF docs in Form Recognizer. I see the forms in blob, the app has Reader access to the blob, and I see labels.json and ocr.json files are created in the blob.  When I try to train the model I get the error:  InvalidContentSourceFormat: Invalid content source: Could not read build content.

I don't see any relevant logs or error messages, but I'm sure I'm not looking in the right place. I"m a bit of newbie to Azure so I appreciate your input and assistance!

I have looked at activity logs for the blob storage, checked if the resource group is locked, checked that the Form Recognizer has a reader role for the blob.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the scenario, I have created a custom form recognizer training using [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code/blob/master/python/FormRecognizer/rest/python-labeled-data.md) and [sample pdf form data](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-REST-api-samples/blob/master/curl/form-recognizer/sample_data_with_labels.zip)

The error message "InvalidContentSourceFormat: Invalid content source: Could not read build content" indicates that there is an issue with the content source access you are trying to use to train the model.

As per the details provided in question I have generated a SAS URL to blob storage  container with Read Permission and it was giving access error.

To solve this, while generating the **SAS URL** to blob storage container give these permissions:

- Read
- List

Generate SAS URL:(https://i.imgur.com/qYh2wzT.png)

As mention in the [azure sample code,](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code/blob/master/python/FormRecognizer/rest/python-labeled-data.md)
With this I'm able to access the data and train the model.

Data Access:(https://i.imgur.com/jKT4qct.png)

Training:(https://i.imgur.com/x5krhN2.png)

Please also check/validate these in the sample code for more details:

- prefix
- includeSubFolders
- useLabelFile
- layout of labels.json and OCR.json