# Azure Form Recognizer Training Issue - InvalidContentSourceFormat Error

Tags: artificial-intelligence, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer, custom-training

I have been experiencing with the Form Recognizer resource on Azure. Despite following the instructions and guidelines provided meticulously, I have been encountering consistent errors during the AI training process.

The specific error message that appears is as follows: "InvalidContentSourceFormat: Invalid content source: Could not read build content." I encounter this error message every time I attempt to train the AI.

I have made multiple attempts to resolve the issue, ensuring that the content source format is compatible with the requirements and guidelines provided. However, the issue still persists, which is disrupting the functionality and overall progress of my project.

Could you please assist in diagnosing the root cause of this problem and suggest a potential resolution? Any advice on how I might proceed would be most appreciated.

Please let me know if you require further details or context.

I was attempting to train my AI model using the Azure Form Recognizer resource. I had followed the instructions provided in the Azure documentation to set up the resource and prepare my training data. My expectation was that the AI would train successfully and then I would be able to proceed with deploying the trained model for my project.

Comment: Please give details such as error logs, guide/tutorial used and other details to reproduce the issue. Other than this the error cause might be due to  invalid trainings data layout and access. So, please check this threads which gives relevant details to validate  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76424890/form-recognizer-train-fails-invalidcontentsourceformat-invalid-content-source

Comment: The problem was that when I placed the path of the blob storage, I put /folderA/folderB. and this what it did was create in the storage due to the first / a folder <no-name> inside folderA and so on, this no-name was the one that did not allow access to the source

Comment: you can try removing the first / from the path of the blob storage. This should prevent the creation of the <no-name> folder.

Answer (score -1):

Removing the leading / from the blob storage path solved the problem for me.

As @naveen-sharma commented on your question. Thanks [@naveen-sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20059423/naveen-sharma)